# Adding a header to the beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am preparing my presentation and I saw a template that has a black header (works like the outline) and I want to add a similar one to my project, I also want the header color to be like the color behind "My name" in the footer

Here is my project in overleaf which contains "My Project" and the one I "want its header"

Edit: I deleted overleaf link because the problem has been solved, in case you are interested you can see the code in the accepted answer

Note: I couldn't give you a specific code because I actually do not know how that kind of headers work

Comment: Post your sample code here, as well as a link to the inspiration for what you want. I can't speak for others, but I'm sure not going to sign up for an Overleaf account and give them my personal information just because you don't want to create a proper [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: I totally understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in your preamble:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%THEME%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\usefonttheme{default}  
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{miniframes} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=gray} %<<<<<<<

\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white!50!MSUgreen} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=white!85!MSUgreen, bg=MSUgreen} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

[image: a]

**UPDATE** after follow-up question

Using `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}` to have the dots of the header arranged horizontally

[image: b]

Comment: Thank you! it works but why are some dots arranged vertically? is there a way to make them in horizontal manner? @Simon Dispa

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a new row of dots is created for each subsection of the section. If you don't use subsections, all the dots will be lined up horizontally. Alternatively you can use the `compress` option, i.e., `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}` and it'll use only one row.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks a lot, the compress option solved the problem